# Could not enable mobile hotspot function on HTC One X

Tags: wifi-hotspot, htc-one-x, ad-hoc-networks

I am using HTC One X and I was trying to enable mobile hotspot function, so I could enjoy internet from my PC adhoc wireless network but it says :

```
 There is a temporary network problem that prevents the 
 enablement of the Mobile Hotspot function. 
 Please retry later.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've messed up some terms:

> I was trying to enable mobile hotspot function, so I could enjoy internet from my PC adhoc wireless network

First: the mobile hotspot function is to share your Android device's mobile Internet connection to other devices not having Internet on their own, e.g. a tablet or laptop, via WiFi.

Second: only few Android devices support ad-hoc networks. There are solutions, but all of them require your device to be rooted.

Third: if you wanted to use your PC's Internet connection on your Android device, that would be [reverse-tether](/questions/tagged/reverse-tether), and again require root to be established.

Comment: Thank you @Izzy, can you provide me links for your second and third solution. I have rooted my phone.

Comment: Simply click on the relevant tags: [ad-hoc-networks](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ad-hoc-networks?sort=faq) and [reverse-tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether?sort=faq). As those questions are already answered, we don't need to repeat the same solutions again :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Mobile network` in Settings is `ON`.

To change timeout time on the HTC One X, do the following:

1. Settings
2. More
3. Portable Hot Spot Tethering
4. Portable WiFi Hotspot Settings
5. Menu at top right
6. Advanced
7. Power Mode
8. Always On

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Install open garden. It's fabulous. Don't have to root or get a mod Rom. It uses best available option between Bluetooth..WiFi and infra red to keep android phone continuously tethered to your devices. Im loving it

Comment: What's your relationship with this app? If you want to recommend or promote it, it might help to include a link.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem three days. and Today I'm happy. Because I found the answer. Some Carriers such AT&T (my Case) use to block mobile hotspot feature. You may want to solve it as I did. I flashed/install the ODEX for my HTC ONE (M7, Not ONE X) Stock rom. But solution should be very similar.

Before flashing it, you need to consider prerequisites. (1) Root your device (2) install a Recovery Manager  (I recommend the "TeamWin Projects - TWRP 2.5")
(3) Download the ODEX or DE-ODEX, depending on your current rom.

Please visit the next reference, I did it and it Works :) x 1000

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2285047

Good Luck!!!

Comment: So, what's the answer? All I see is a link.